# How to replace rows with character value by integers in a column in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am working on one large dataset, the problem am facing is that there are columns that have all integer values, however, as the dataset is uncleaned there are a few rows where there are 'characters' along with integers. Here am trying to illustrate the problem with a small pandas dataframe example,

I have the following dataframe:

| Index | l1 | l2 | l3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 123 | 23 |
| 1 | 2 | Z3V | 343 |
| 2 | 3 | 321 | 21 |
| 3 | 4 | AZ34 | 345 |
| 4 | 5 | 432 | 3 |

With dataframe code :

```py
l1,l2,l3 = [1,2,3,4,5], [123, 'Z3V', 321, 'AZ34', 432], [23,343,21,345,3]
data = pd.DataFrame(zip(l1,l2,l3), columns=['l1', 'l2', 'l3'])
print(data)
```

Here as you can see, column 'l2' at rows index 1 and 3 have 'characters' along with integers. I want to find such rows in this particular column and print them. Later I want to replace them with integer values like 100 or something similar integer. i.e. those numbers that I am replacing with will be different for example, am replacing instances of 'Z3V' with 100 and instances of 'AZ34' with 101. My point is to replace characters containing values with integers. Now, if in 'l2' column, 'Z3V' occurs again, there too, I will replace it with 100.

Expected output :

| Index | l1 | l2 | l3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 123 | 23 |
| 1 | 2 | 100 | 343 |
| 2 | 3 | 321 | 21 |
| 3 | 4 | 101 | 345 |
| 4 | 5 | 432 | 3 |

As you can see, the two instances where there were characters have been replaced with 100 and 101 respectively

How to get this expected output ?

Comment: Please add a DataFrame representation that can be copied into a text editor

Comment: What is the logic behind 100 and 101 being replacement values?

Comment: @DaniMesejo added dataframe code

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen clarified the logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# setup
l1, l2, l3 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [123, 'Z3V', 321, 'AZ34', 432, 'Z3V'], [23, 343, 21, 345, 3, 3]
data = pd.DataFrame(zip(l1, l2, l3), columns=['l1', 'l2', 'l3'])

# find all non numeric values across the whole DataFrame
mask = data.applymap(np.isreal)
rows, cols = np.where(~mask)

# create the replacement dictionary 
replacements = {k: i for i, k in enumerate(np.unique(data.values[rows, cols]), 100)}

# apply the replacements
res = data.replace(replacements)
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
   l1   l2   l3
0   1  123   23
1   2  101  343
2   3  321   21
3   4  100  345
4   5  432    3
5   6  101    3
```

Note that I added an extra row to verify the desire behaviour, now the `data` DataFrame looks like:

```
   l1    l2   l3
0   1   123   23
1   2   Z3V  343
2   3   321   21
3   4  AZ34  345
4   5   432    3
5   6   Z3V    3
```

By changing this line:

```
# create the replacement dictionary
replacements = {k: i for i, k in enumerate(np.unique(data.values[rows, cols]), 100)}
```

you can change the replacement values as you see fit.